# UMVUE of parameter from Zero Truncated Poission distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, poisson-distribution, umvue

Let $x_1,...,x_n$ have the distribution

$$
P(X = x) = \frac{\theta^xe^{-\theta}}{x!(1-e^{-\theta})}, \ \ x = 1,2,3...
$$

Now we want to find UMVUE for $e^{-\theta}$. My first thought was to apply the Rao-Blackwell theorem with help from the complete sufficient statistic $\sum x_i$. For a standard Poisson, the UMVUE would easily be found applying the Lehmann–Scheffé theorem using $P(X = 0) = e^{-\theta}$. But for the the zero-truncated, the Lehmann-Scheffé theorem does not seem to fit the problem. Has anyone a solution to this?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/544225/119261

Comment: @StubbornAtom Any chance to help me this related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808236/find-the-umvue-of-theta-from-zero-truncated-poisson-distribution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you could rewrite the distribution to fit the general form of the exponential family.
$$ \frac{1}{x!}e^{x\log\theta -\theta -\log(1-e^{-\theta})} $$
so the sufficient statistics is $T:=x$, $\eta:=\log\theta$ and $A(\eta):=-e^\eta-\log(1-e^{-e^\eta})$. By properties of the exponential family

$$\mathbb{E}[T]=\frac{\partial A(\eta)}{\partial\eta}=\frac{e^{\eta+e^\eta}}{1-e^{e^\eta}}:= \frac{\theta e^{\theta}}{1-e^\theta}$$

and now you can construct your unbiased estimator as
$$ \hat{e^\theta}=\left\lbrace z:\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=\frac{z\log z}{1-z}\right\rbrace$$
which will be UMVUE by the Lehmann-Scheffé theorem.

Comment: I am confused. How did you construct the unbiased estimator in your last step?

Comment: Note that the empirical expectation of $T$ is simply the mean of all $\{x_i\}_{i\in[n]}$. Then, we let $z:=e^\theta$ and use the expression of $\mathbb{E}[T]$ to determine this quantity.

Comment: I see how $\hat{z}$ can be derived from $\bar{ x}$. But it is not so clear why that derived $\hat{z}$ should also be unbiased.

Comment: So, if we have $E[T] = f(\theta)$ does that make the derived estimator $\hat\theta = f^{-1}(T)$ in general unbiased?

Comment: Refer to the theorem I invoke in the reply: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem

Comment: Can you answer this related question for me? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808236/find-the-umvue-of-theta-from-zero-truncated-poisson-distribution